# PL/SQL - conditional compilation specific to one database

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have an Oracle development database that has some packages that end up getting copied to production servers. I'm looking for a way to use conditional compilation in the package spec that is only true on this one development server, but compiles to false on all other servers.

I can't add anything to the Production servers to accomplish this - no new global variable/config settings/procedures/etc.

So is there a way to effectively do

```
$IF {{development_server}} $THEN
    my_proc;
$END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if this is precisely what you are after, but it should give you something to work with:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE my_app_state
   AUTHID DEFINER
IS
   c_in_production   CONSTANT BOOLEAN := TRUE;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_app_state
   AUTHID DEFINER
IS
   PROCEDURE my_proc1 
   IS
   BEGIN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('1');
   END;

   PROCEDURE my_proc2
   IS
   BEGIN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('2');
   END;
BEGIN
   $if my_app_state.c_in_production $then
      my_proc1;
   $else
      my_proc2;
   $end
end;
/

EXEC test_app_state
```

You can also use a conditional compilation flag. If it is undefined, it simply defaults to NULL, so the default production state of affairs is "off".

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_app_state
   AUTHID DEFINER
IS
   PROCEDURE my_proc1 
   IS
   BEGIN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('1');
   END;

   PROCEDURE my_proc2
   IS
   BEGIN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('2');
   END;
BEGIN
   $if $$cc_in_dev $then
      my_proc1;
   $else
      my_proc2;
   $end
end;
/
```

Comment: What an honor to have a reply from the PL/SQL master himself - I'm currently using something very similar what you've set out here (referencing a schema.package.variable), but my variable is in a schema/package that exists only on my development server so it gives an error when I go to compile the package on the Production servers.


There are dozens of Production servers a package could be copied to, so I can't afford to set a variable in every environment. If there was a way to wrap the variable in a "if variable doesn't exist/hits an exception, false" then I would be in business.

Comment: So you want a certain behavior to be turned on in dev, but in production the default state is off? In that case, use a conditional compilation flag. If undefined, that defaults to null. I will edit my solution to reflect this. By the way, I am honored that you are honored. :-)

Comment: The ccflag is just what I was looking for, thanks again for the help and everything you do in the PL/SQL community.

Answer (score 0):

v$database has the database name in it.  If they're named differently this should work.

```
SELECT NAME FROM v$database;
```

Comment: Unfortunately these are the same between environments since the Development server is set up to mirror the production server.